# Sort Multiple Elements of the same type in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

Basically I have the following that is rendered by PHP:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child" data-sort=2>2</div>
    <div class="child" data-sort=1>1</div>
    <div class="child" data-sort=3>3</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="child" data-sort=1>1</div>
    <div class="child" data-sort=3>3</div>
    <div class="child" data-sort=2>2</div>
    <div class="child" data-sort=2>2</div>
</div>
```

and what I want returned is:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child" data-sort=1>1</div>
    <div class="child" data-sort=2>2</div>
    <div class="child" data-sort=3>3</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="child" data-sort=1>1</div>
    <div class="child" data-sort=2>2</div>
    <div class="child" data-sort=2>2</div>
    <div class="child" data-sort=3>3</div>
</div>
```

So basically it must sort multiple instances of the parent based on the data sort attribute of each child while still maintaing its state within the parent element.

How would you use jQuery to target each parent element and then sort each child within that parent based on the data-sort attribute.

This is the closest I have come, but it does not render anything:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery.each('.parent', function(index, val) {
        jQuery(jQuery(this).children('.child')).sort(function(a,b){
            return a.dataset.sort > b.dataset.sort;
        }).appendTo(this);
    });
});
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, of course, not, jQuery objects [don't have a `sort` method](http://api.jquery.com/sort).

Comment: I think it's easier to change output order in your PHP .

Comment: Output is based on ajax request so I cant chose the order in which the data is returned. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: Also note that as you're accepting the `$` argument in your `ready` callback, you can use `$` for `jQuery` within that callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've tried to use a `sort` method on a jQuery object, but they don't have (a documented) one. Arrays have a `sort`, though, and then if you append the sorted array, the children get moved:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.parent').each(function() {
        var p = $(this);
        p.append(p.children(".child").get().sort(function(a, b) {
            return $(a).attr("data-sort") - $(b).attr("data-sort");
        }));
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child" data-sort=2>2</div>
    <div class="child" data-sort=1>1</div>
    <div class="child" data-sort=3>3</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="child" data-sort=1>1</div>
    <div class="child" data-sort=3>3</div>
    <div class="child" data-sort=2>2</div>
    <div class="child" data-sort=2>2</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

How that works:

- We loop through the `.parent` elements
- Within those, we get the children, and get an **array** of them by using `.get()`
- Then we sort that array, using a callback that makes use of the fact that when you use the binary `-` operator on strings, they get converted to numbers; so `$(a).attr("data-sort") - $(b).attr("data-sort")` ends up being negative of `a`'s order was lower than `b`'s, `0` if they were the same, or positive if `b`'s order was higher than `a`'s
- ...and append it to parent again, which moves the elements

Note that the above assumes that either there are no non-`.child` children in `.parent` elements, or that you want the `.child` children to end up *after* any other children in the `.parent`.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over each parent element and sort their child elements using [Array.sort](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp):

```
var parent = $('.parent');
parent.each(function(){
   $(this).find('.child').sort(function (a, b) {
        return +a.dataset.sort - +b.dataset.sort;
   }).appendTo($(this));
});
```

### Working Demo

Comment: jquery elements object is nothing but array of elements. surely you can pass the object and write the condition to use each objects property to perform sort.

Comment: If you think jQuery objects are arrays, you're simply mistaken. They are **array-like**, but they are not arrays. They do not have all array features, nor is it safe to assume that undocumented features will exist from one dot rev to the next.

Comment: also i never mentioned that sort is jquery method

Comment: No, you just called `sort` on a jQuery instance. Which is exactly the same thing.

Comment: we also use `object.length` and not `object.get().length` to get objects length. that does not mean length is property of jquery.

Comment: [`length` **is** a documented property of jQuery objects](http://api.jquery.com/length/)

Comment: oh.did not knew that.

Answer (score 0):

since you are consturcting this in php why not constuct sorted data there itself. something like this:

```
<?php 
$arr[0] =array(2,1,3);
$arr[1] =array(1,3,2,2);
$data="";
foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
$data .="<div class='parent'>";
$x=$val;
sort($x);
foreach($x as $k=>$v){
    $data .="<div class='child' data-sort=$v>$v</div>";
}
$data .="</div>";

}
var_dump($data);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
$('.parent').each(function(index, val) {
    $this = $(this);
    sorted = $this.children().sort(function(a,b) {
        var vA = parseInt($(a).data("sort"));
        var vB = parseInt($(b).data("sort"));
        return (vA < vB) ? -1 : 1;
    })  
    $(sorted).appendTo($this);
});
```

working example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/0fLjre1w/1/)